# Can South Korean passport holder temporarily living in Vietnam enter EU countries?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, paperwork, covid-19, south-korean-citizens

I am a South Korean passport holder who's been in Vietnam since early this year. I am in Vietnam on an extended tourist visa, not as a resident.

I would like to leave Vietnam and enter any EU countries that opened their border to Korean citizens (like Greece, Denmark, for example). However, I found the entry requirement of each country to be quite unclear if me being a Korean passport holder is enough to enter the country or I should have stayed in Korea before coming to these EU countries.

Does anybody have a similar situation or an answer for this?

Comment: Do you mean in terms of visa-free entry (which are based on nationality, in most cases) or in terms of Covid-related restrictions (which are based on where you have been in the last two weeks, mostly)?

Comment: It varies from country to country. Which EU country do you want to fly to first (that's the important bit)?

Comment: @Crazydre From what I see, Greece seems to have the most relaxed entry requirement but I am not sure if they accept people based on nationality or on places of one that has been recently. (Korean embassy of Greece is not answering my messages)

Comment: @jcaron COVID-related restriction. Many EU countries announced they welcome residents from Korea (as well as ppl from AU, NZ, Japan, Thailand...) - but I'm not sure if it means people coming FROM Korea or people with Korean passport. I'm hoping to find a country that requires the latter.

Comment: @sisis "Residents of South Korea" means you live in South Korea. YOur passport or where you fly from doesn't matter. In practice, with a South Korean passport they'll usually just assume you live there

Answer (score 4):

As of 10.08.2020, as a South Korean citizen and resident flying from Vietnam, you can enter the Schengen Area through the following countries:

- Czechia
- Denmark
- Estonia
- Finland (if flying directly from Cyprus, Japan, South Korea or Thailand)
- France (if flying directly from Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Georgia, Ireland, Japan, Morocco, Romania, South Korea, Thailand, Tunisia or the UK)
- Germany
- Hungary (if flying directly from Bulgaria, Canada, China, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, Japan, Romania, Russia, Serbia, South Korea the UK or the US)
- Italy (if not having spent the past 14 days in Algeria, Armenia, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Brazil, Chile, Dominican Republic, Kuwait, Moldova, Montenegro, North Macedonia, Oman, Panama, Peru or Serbia)
- Latvia
- Lithuania
- Luxembourg
- Malta (if flying directly from Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, Jordan, Morocco, Romania, Tunisia, Turkey, the UAE or the UK)
- Netherlands
- Poland (if flying directly from Albania,
  Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Georgia, Ireland, Japan, Montenegro, Romania, South Korea or the UK)
- Portugal (if flying directly from Algeria, Bulgaria, Canada, China, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, Morocco, Romania, Tunisia or the UK)
- Slovakia (if flying directly from Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, Montenegro, or the UK)
- Slovenia
- Spain (if flying directly from Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, Romania or the UK)
- Sweden
- Switzerland (if flying directly from Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, Japan, Morocco, Romania, South Korea, Thailand Tunisia or the UK)

Answer (score 1):

> However, I found the entry requirement of each country to be quite unclear if me being a Korean passport holder is enough to enter the country or I should have stayed in Korea before coming to these EU countries.

Each EU country has its own policy, but looking at the case of France for example, being a Korean passport holder is not enough (quote from [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm) and echoed by https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/FRA):

> - **passengers arriving from** Andorra, Australia, Canada, Georgia, Japan, **Korea (Rep.)**, Monaco, Morocco, New-Zealand, Rwanda, San Marino, Switzerland, Thailand, Tunisia, United Kingdom, Uruguay, Vatican City (Holy See) or an EEA Member State;

which needless to say, makes the most sense.

---

Full [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm) information for France:

> France Published 01.08.2020
>
> 1. Passengers are not allowed to enter.
>
> - This does not apply to:
> - nationals of France, if not arriving from French Guiana or Mayotte, and their spouses and children;
> - British nationals and nationals of Andorra, Monaco, San Marino, Switzerland, Vatican City (Holy See) and an EEA Member State if not
>   arriving from French Guiana or Mayotte; and their spouses and
>   children;
> - passengers arriving from Andorra, Australia, Canada, Georgia, Japan, Korea (Rep.), Monaco, Morocco, New-Zealand, Rwanda, San Marino,
>   Switzerland, Thailand, Tunisia, United Kingdom, Uruguay, Vatican City
>   (Holy See) or an EEA Member State;
> - passengers with a residence permit issued by Andorra, Monaco, San Marino, Switzerland, United Kingdom, Vatican City (Holy See) or an EEA
>   Member State if not arriving from French Guiana or Mayotte;
> - merchant seamen if not arriving from French Guiana or Mayotte;
> - students if not arriving from French Guiana or Mayotte.
>
> 2. Passengers arriving from Bahrain, Panama, USA or United Arab Emirates must have a medical certificate with a negative Coronavirus
>    (COVID-19) PCR test result issued at most 72 hours before departure.
>
> - This does not apply to passengers younger than 11 years.
>
> 3. Passengers arriving from Algeria, Brazil, India, Israel, Kuwait, Madagascar, Oman, Peru, Qatar, Serbia, South Africa or Turkey must
>    have a medical certificate with a negative Coronavirus (COVID-19) PCR
>    test result issued at most 72 hours before departure. Passengers
>    without a medical certificate must take the test on arrival.
>
> - This does not apply to passengers younger than 11 years.
>
> 4. A completed International Travel Certificate must be presented prior to boarding and to immigration upon arrival or when transiting
>    France. The certificate can be obtained at consulates or at
>    https://www.interieur.gouv.fr.
>
> - This does not apply to passengers arriving from Andorra, Australia, Canada, Georgia, Japan, Korea (Rep.), Monaco, Morocco, New-Zealand,
>   Rwanda, San Marino, Switzerland, Thailand, Tunisia, United Kingdom,
>   Uruguay, Vatican City (Holy See) or an EEA Member State.
>
> 5. Passengers must complete a declaration on honor to state that they do not have symptoms of Coronavirus (COVID-19).
> 6. Passengers are subject to quarantine or isolation.

Comment: THat's France. Greece, meanwhile, bases it on residency, in line with the EU "default"

Comment: @Crazydre Yes, each EU country has its own policy.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully entered Greece from Vietnam without any problem. (the immigration officer didn't ask anything where I am coming from)

Comment: When did this occur? How long were you in Vietnam before departing for Greece? Where did you change planes?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I was in Vietnam for 6 months on an extended tourist visa. I transited in Doha, Qatar. Contacted 3 consulates (the Greek embassy in Korea, the Korean embassy in Greece, the Greek embassy in Vietnam) and they gave me all different answers. Luckily, Qatar airline in Vietnam office confirmed I had the right to board on the plane and the immigration office in Athens didn't question me anything!